# When calling navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice on Opera I get "Web Bluetooth API globally disabled" error

Tags: bluetooth, opera

I am trying this on Mac OS, latest OS and Opera. I have seen the advice on the Web about enabling bluetooth via Opera flags, but there is no specific Bluetooth API flag listed. I have tried enabling possible related flags of "experimental javascript technologies", with no success. Google Chrome works, so its not the OS.

How do I get the Bluetooth Web API enabled in Opera for Mac OS?

Comment: Same problem on Brave, Chrome and Edge working fine